# QEMU: Boot Failed: EFI Hard Drive

Tags: macos, virtualbox, qemu, kvm

I am attempting to create a Mac VM for development. Following the guide in [this script](https://github.com/myspaghetti/macos-guest-virtualbox), I managed to create a functioning VirtualBox machine with Mojave installed. Now, this script mentions that I can ["import the VM into KVM/QEMU for near-native performance"](https://github.com/myspaghetti/macos-guest-virtualbox#performance-and-unsupported-features), which I attempted to do, first by converting the `.vdi` disk into a `.qcow2`.

However, when I try to launch a VM via `qemu-system-x86_64` with this disk, it fails to boot, with the message `Boot Failed: EFI Hard Drive`. It then attempts to boot from the network.

Command:
`qemu-system-x86_64 -hda Mojave.qcow2 -m 4096 -smp 2 -machine q35 -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd`

I've also tried various combinations of ways to specify the drive, e.g. `-drive`, `-hda`; none of these worked.

What am I doing wrong? If it's at all relevant, I am running Linux Mint 18.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but in my case my host linux was debian9, vm debian9 and -machine pc-i440fx-xenial . When installed ovmv using apt-get I got "0~20160408.ffea0a2c-2" version , which I am pretty sure it quite old.  So recommend try to build OVMF.fd from latest stable branch or https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/files/904571/ovmf_x64.zip .

Ref: https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/issues/875